# How to give space between 2 words after removing Punctuation and Numbers text mining in R

Tags: regex, r, gsub, tm

We can see that in the below example after removing number 3054 and punctuation marks - in given string `"BG3054-suhas B-DC chr 23.7-22.8.13"` the output will combine as `bgsuhas` but i need a space between this two word as `bg suhas`. Same thing you can see in below given string as `bdc, bbxsh`. Can you help me to a space between these words for text mining.

I need like this
`bg suhas b dc chr rashmi` as an output matrix

```
Newcol<-c("BG3054-suhas B-DC chr 23.7-22.8.13","BBXSH0030 Rashmi S 23.4.13to22.5.13")

text.corp <- Corpus(VectorSource(Newcol))   

text.corp <- tm_map(text.corp, tolower)

text.corp <- tm_map(text.corp, stripWhitespace)

text.corp <- tm_map(text.corp, removeNumbers)

text.corp <- tm_map(text.corp, removePunctuation)

text.corp <- tm_map(text.corp, removeWords, c("the", stopwords("english")))

dtm <- DocumentTermMatrix(text.corp)

dtm.mat <- as.matrix(dtm)

dtm.mat

OUTPUT
    Terms
Docs bbxsh bdc bgsuhas chr rashmi
   1     0   1       1   1      0
   2     1   0       0   0      1
```

Answer (score 3):

I would just replace anything that's not an a-z letter with a space as a preprocessing step using `gsub`:

```
Newcol <- gsub("[^a-zA-Z]+", " ", Newcol)
Newcol
# [1] "BG suhas B DC chr " "BBXSH Rashmi S to "
```

Then your `tm` code should work fine for processing `Newcol`.

Answer (score 3):

Define your own content transformer:

`replacePunctuation <- content_transformer(function(x) {return (gsub("[[:punct:]]"," ", x))})`

And then use it:

`text.corp <- tm_map(text.corp, replacePunctuation )`